# Invalid mex file error during simulink the model

Tags: canoe

I am getting invalid mex file error while running model based project in MATLAB (64-bit on Windows 10 32-bit).

`Error while obtaining sizes from MEX S-function 'sigin' in 'WiperSensSyt/Signal Input1/S-Function'. Caused by: Invalid MEX-file "path"  The specified module could not be found.`

I used canoe I/O block with model based development. and installed the Vector CANoe Matlab Integration Package for Matlab. during building the model it gives this error for all canoe i/o blocks. but all the mex file is present in above package.

I check on dependency walker it shows the lot of dll is missing for mex file but the dlls is present in the matlab folder.